# Android: Intent#getExtras() is always null, nothing helps

Tags: android, android-intent

When I create **a new Intent in an Activity**:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, TargetActivity.class);
// apply hacks explained in above stackoverflow answers
System.out.println(myIntent.getExtras())
```

(this code lays in a default blank activity)

`Intent#getExtras()` is always `null` and thus `Intent#putExtras(...)` leads to immediate `NullPointerException`. Starting the Intent, however, works without any problems.

I've read all similar stackoverflow posts about this topic:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/6357330
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/14288868
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/16458878
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/16377139
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/13596581
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/24047080
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/3128271

I've tried them all, but none of them seems to have any effect.

Could anyone please provide a solution to simply start an Intent with non-null extras which *always works*?

Alternatively, is there any other way to provide extra information to an Intent which is clean and not leaky?

Comment: `thus Intent#putExtras(...) leads to immediate NullPointerException`. I don't think so. The source for `Intent` has a check for null and initialize the Extras when you first call `putExtras`

Comment: What did you expect ? you call intent.getExtras before adding any data to the Intent..

Comment: None of those links you posted seem to apply directly to just trying to pass an extra in an Intent from one Activity to another.  Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android/7325248#7325248

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the problem. Thank you @DanielNugent for pointing to the canonical answer to Intent handling.

The problem was: when I did

```
myIntent .putExtra("myVar", myVar);
```

`myVar` was `null`!

Stupid of me I didn't double check that and panic, put somehow stupid of Android that this does indeed lead to immediate `NullPointerException`! Please try it yourself if you don't believe me.

@njzk2: Thank you, I didn't realize that.